# Align textview to display text under toolbar imageviews

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to put text underneath the icons that are clicked in the bottom toolbar. The text won't go under however and looks like this:

[image: not right]

But it want it to look like this:

[image: right]

I am using a LinearLayout with the following header:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@color/white">
```

My code looks like this (two of these for each icon):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/nav_wallet"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_wallet" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#8a000000"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
    android:text="@string/wallet_label" />
```

Comment: What happens if you remove weight and spacing from ImageView?

Comment: Please make use of BottomNavigation!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, was able to solve it by placing each textview and imageview into a linearlayout and spacing them from there.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nav_wallet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_wallet" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#8a000000"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
        android:text="@string/wallet_label" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nav_transactions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_transactions" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#8a000000"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
        android:text="@string/tx_label" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nav_browser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_browser" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#8a000000"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
        android:text="@string/browser_label" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#8a000000"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
        android:text="@string/settings_label" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply enclose your TextView and ImageView in a LinearLayout.
Ofcourse you need to adjust the width of the LinearLayout also.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nav_wallet"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_wallet" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#8a000000"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
        android:text="@string/wallet_label" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You might also have to play around with weights a little bit to get the result you want, since I do not know the full XML code I can not tell you the exact weights you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout and use equal weight for all 4 columns. Also, can have single Textview below is sample code

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableBottom="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
            android:text="Hello" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nav_wallet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableBottom="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
            android:text="Hello" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableBottom="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
            android:text="Hello" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableBottom="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
            android:text="Hello" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

From you snippet it seems that you are having an horizontal LinearLayout as a parent for your images and texts. The result is that you have all your items aligned horizontally. As a solution you can have each item (text and image) in its own vertical layout and have these layouts placed in your parent horizontal LinearLayout. But this solution creates a deeper view hierarchy, which is not really a problem with today's phones, but it is not a best practice. 
A better solution in which you keep your current parent layout would be to use a compoundDrawable like:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/wallet_label" 
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_wallet"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Of course you could also use a ConstraintLayout. There are definitely  more than one solution to your problem.